# Uninstalling IE 10 Using a batch file

Tags: internet-explorer-10

I found a way to uninstall IE 10 using a batch file which below and it works great like it's suppose to. It uninstalls and restarts the computer after about a minute.

FORFILES /P %WINDIR%\servicing\Packages /M Microsoft-Windows-InternetExplorer-*10.*.mum /c "cmd /c echo Uninstalling package @fname && start /w pkgmgr /up:@fname /norestart /quiet"

shutdown -r

But I wanted to take this further and Hide IE 10 from windows updates which will prevent windows to install this update actually in the future and to do that, Microsoft provides an executable file which you can download from here

*http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=36512* After extracting this executable, you get 3 files, IE10_Blocker.adm, IE_blocker.cmd and IE10_BlockerHelp.htm and Microsoft instructions are "In the Command Prompt, goto the folder where you have extracted these 3 files and type “ie9_blocker.cmd /B” and hit Enter to set the blocker on the machine."

I decided to make one batch file for all this so right now I got this far.

FORFILES /P %WINDIR%\servicing\Packages /M Microsoft-Windows-InternetExplorer-*10.*.mum /c "cmd /c echo Uninstalling package @fname && start /w pkgmgr /up:@fname /norestart /quiet" 
mkdir “C:\IE10”
copy /Y \file01p\Users\test\public\IE Update blocker\IE10*.* “C:\IE10”
start /d C:IE10\IE10_Blocker.cmd /b 
shutdown -r

mkdir “C:\IE10” This command is suppose to create the directory called IE10 on C drive

copy /Y \file01p\Users\test\public\IE Update blocker\IE10*.* “C:\IE10” This command will copy those executable from the network public folders to their C:\IE10 which I just created in the previous step.

This script doesn't work. Only up to uninstalling IE 10 it works but it doesn't create the directory and so it doesn't copy the files from the network. How can do this?

Thanks

Thanks

Comment: well this was a useless attempt.

Answer (score 0):

Try running your batch as administrator.

in an administrator : command prompt it makes the directory without issue.
also, it could be that you do not have access to make the directory on C:
you could try locating it elsewhere that you are sure you have write access.